# ArcGIS Online Dashboard change date format in advanced formatting

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade, operations-dashboard, formatting

I have set up an ArcGIS Online Dashboard using a custom data expression that uses variables for dates as follow:

```
var start = ToLocal(Date(1970, 0, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0));
var dtpoletbl = DateDiff(t.CreationDate, start, 'milliseconds');
var edtpolegeom = DateDiff(p.EditedDate, start, 'milliseconds');
```

CreationDate and EditedDate are fields within different layers.

Then in return I can see these dates by default in the format dd MMMM yyyy on a dashboard widget e.g.

```
24 April 2023
```

I have set up a table where I can show fields that I need to show. For one of them it was useful to set up advanced formatting to highlight specific values with different colours. in doing that I noticed that the date formatting dramatically changed to the "full" format like this:

```
Mon Apr 24 2023 12:41:36 GMT+0100 (*** Standard Time)
```

I tried to see the documentation on date formats but I can't figure out how to set for example a variable that modifies the date formatting from another variable as I wish. There are three functions for `Date`, but they are not meant to digest another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck changing the formatting after switching to advanced formatting? It not only resets/ignores date formats but also removes/ignores the domains and only shows the code value.

Update... Got it:

```
displayText: Text($datapoint.your_date_field, 'MMMM DD YYYY')
```

Also for the domains:

```
displayText: DomainName($datapoint, 'your_field')
```